# FastApi sqlalchemy Connection was closed in the middle of operation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, uvicorn, asyncpg

I have an async FastApi application with async sqlalchemy, source code (will not provide schemas.py because it is not necessary):

### database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api import DeclarativeMeta

from app.config import settings


engine = create_async_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL)
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


class Titles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "titles"
    id = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(100), unique=True)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

### routers.py

```
import .database
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter


router = InferringRouter()


async def get_titles(session: AsyncSession):
    results = await session.execute(select(database.Titles)))
    return results.scalars().all()


@cbv(router)
class TitlesView:
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(database.get_session)

    @router.get("/titles", status_code=HTTP_200_OK)
    async def get(self) -> List[TitlesSchema]:
        results = await get_titles(self.session)
        return [TitlesSchema.from_orm(result) for result in results]
```

### main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app.routers import router 


def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()
    app .include_router(routers, prefix="/", tags=["Titles"])

    return printer_app


app = create_app()
```

It runs with docker:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--limit-max-requests", "10000"]
```

And it has Postgres database with default settings in docker too. It all runs at docker-swarm. Works fine at first, accepts all requests. But if you leave it for 15-30 minutes (I did not count), and then make a request, it will not work:

```
<class 'asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError'>: connection was closed in the middle of operation
```

And right after that I send the next request and it doesn't throw an error. What could it be? How do I get rid of the ConnectionDoesNotExistError?

Comment: At postgresql container i see:
    LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve that using `pool_pre_ping` setting like that:

```
engine = create_async_engine(DB_URL, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html

Comment: In your question you are using create_async_engine and here just create_engine. Did you switch to not using async engine?

Comment: No, sorry, I did not change anything. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I will quote the answer from [here](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/309#issuecomment-423506987), I think it might be useful. All credit to q210.

> In our case, the root cause was that ipvs, used by swarm to route packets, have default expiration time for idle connections set to 900 seconds. So if connection had no activity for more than 15 minutes, ipvs broke it.
> 900 seconds is significantly less than default linux tcp keepalive setting (7200 seconds) used by most of the services that can send keepalive tcp packets to keep connections from going idle.
>
> The same problem is described here [moby/moby#31208](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31208)
>
> To fix this we had to set the following in postgresql.conf:
>
> ```
> tcp_keepalives_idle = 600               # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
>                                        # 0 selects the system default
> tcp_keepalives_interval = 30            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
>                                        # 0 selects the system default
> tcp_keepalives_count = 10               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
>                                        # 0 selects the system default
> ```
>
> These settings are forcing PostgreSQL to keep connections from going idle by sending keepalive packets more often than ipvs default setting (that we can't change in docker-swarm, sadly).
>
> I guess the same could be achieved by changing corresponding linux settings (`net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time` and the like), 'cause PostgreSQL uses them by default, but in our case changing these was a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw this thread and yes it might be helpful for someone. I have exactly the same application, but in Flask, with default DB setup and no error. So I don’t want to change the DB setting and want to solve this error programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with asyncpg. Solve problem by this part of code (docs - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-multiple-asyncio-event-loops )

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

engine = create_async_engine(
    "postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@host/dbname",
    poolclass=NullPool,
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy
I had mistake:
<class 'asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError'>: connection was closed in the middle of operation
after ~5 minutes of inactivity in my app. Try diffirent settings of connections, still the same. Error stops only if i add poolclass=NullPool in connection settings.